# C# | StreamWriter keeps replacing the current lines

Tags: c#, streamwriter

So I have this application where there are 3 textboxes which ask the user for input. When the user has finished filling out the texboxes, there is a button that stores the input into a class.

Now the idea is that as the user presses the button to store the input a class, the input also gets stored into a textfile. The problem that I am facing now is that whenever a user adds new input, the old input gets replaced in the textfile.

This is the code:

```
using (StreamWriter txtFile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Desktop\smtp.txt"))
{
    txtFile.WriteLine(Class_Smtp[Index].SmtpClientName);
    txtFile.WriteLine(Class_Smtp[Index].SmtpPort);
    txtFile.WriteLine(Class_Smtp[Index].SmtpEmailExtension + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Any Ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should append the text

```
using (StreamWriter txtFile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Desktop\smtp.txt", true))
{
    txtFile.WriteLine(Class_Smtp[Index].SmtpClientName);
    txtFile.WriteLine(Class_Smtp[Index].SmtpPort);
    txtFile.WriteLine(Class_Smtp[Index].SmtpEmailExtension + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems that I indeed did forget to pass another parameter. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `StreamWriter` constructor override that accepts a bool parameter to tell it whether to append or replace, and pass `true`:

[`public StreamWriter(string path, bool append)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb.aspx)

For your example:

```
using 
(
    StreamWriter txtFile = new StreamWriter
    (
        @"C:\Users\Desktop\smtp.txt", 
        true // <=== This parameter tells it to append
    )
)
```